# Molly's belly is still inflated after giving birth

Tags: aquarium, reproduction

One of my molly just gave birth to 4 fry. Her belly is still inflated just as it was before giving birth. I was waiting if she's gonna release more babies. She hasn't. She just stay at the bottom of the tank and stay quiet.

Comment: how long ago did she give birth minutes-hours-days? do you have other fish in the tank,please edit more information into your question.

Comment: 4 fry? Definitely on the small side for a molly birth. She probably has more on the way. Molly’s tend to drop 20-50 fry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long does "giving birth" last for a molly?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/23890/how-long-does-giving-birth-last-for-a-molly) the normal time is 8-24hrs but it can take up to two days.